# DNS: internal and external nameservers

Tags: dns

So, I'm on day 3...

I am running an Ubuntu.64-based distribution on a VirtualBox.  I have the need to access both external ISP DNS servers, as well as "internal" DNS servers through an OpenVPN connection.  At times I need to query the external DNS(#*host example.com*) through the **eth0** interface; sometimes I need to query the VPN "internal" DNS (#*host internal.local*) through the **tap0** interface.

My question is: how do I configure my system to query the correct nameserver-- the ISP DNS or the VPN DNS (for attempting zone transfers, for example)?

I've tried editing resolv.conf to include both external and internal nameservers/domains, with no luck (obviously).  I've also tried mitigating the situation with dnsmasq.  That got me close (I think).

I realize I can use dig to set the [@server] based on individual queries, but I would appreciate a systemic resolution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the [PowerDNS recursor](http://doc.powerdns.com/built-in-recursor.html) for exactly this situation before; it is in the package `pdns-recursor`, if you wish to try it. You'll want to set your `/etc/resolv.conf` to query only `127.0.0.1` should you choose to try this approach.

The `forward-zones` directive lets you specify which servers to contact for which zones:

> ```
> forward-zones= ds9a.nl=213.244.168.210, powerdns.com=127.0.0.1
> ```

It does look a little strange, since it is one configuration setting that takes multiple values, but you do get to specify exactly which servers are going to provide answers for which domains.

Comment: Thank you. That worked beautifully. Now to figure out how to backwards resolve...

Comment: [Backwards resolution may be more difficult](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt). I am no longer in an easy position to test this for myself -- this is a _guess_ -- try adding zones `168.192.in-addr.arpa=127.0.0.1` in the same fashion.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I added the addresses for both the local master and the local slave nameservers  to /etc/resolv.conf. I configured my system to check the nameservers in order, so if domain.local 1&2 are entered before 127.0.0.1, when my system checks resolv.conf and tries an internal query, it is picked up and backward resolves. External queries successfully resolve to the local 127.0.0.1 nameserver. Thanks again.